# Php session security hardening

Tags: php, session

I would like to further harden my security of access the pages. What I have currently the very top of every page is this. Some articles suggest that this is not helpful $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] is that true ? I also call some pages by passing get values any best way to secure those input beside using mysql_real_escape_string ?

```
session_start(); 
if(!( isset($_SESSION['eID']) && !empty($_SESSION['eID']) && isset($_SESSION['uID']) && !empty($_SESSION['uID']) && isset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && !empty($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ))
{

}
else
{
  //all other codes goes here.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checking for the existence of HTTP_USER_AGENT won't help you secure your sessions. Someone willing to compromise your website will forge one instantly.

AFAIK, the best way to secure a `$_GET` variable is:

- Ensuring that it is present.
- Checking that its type is correct ([int](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php), [float](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php), [string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-string.php), [array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php), etc.)
- Checking that the content is valid and allowed (example: positive for page numbers, without special characters for strings). For strings, you can use [regular expressions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

Only then you should use `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Example:

```
if(!(isset($_GET['search'] && is_string($_GET['search']) && preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-6 \-"\']/', $_GET['search']))) {
  die("Search was not set or is invalid");
}
do_some_query(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']));
```

---

Also, you should not put this code at the top of all your pages, but instead put it in a function in another file and call it.

Example:

in `sessions.php` (don't put this file where it can be called directly):

```
function check_session() {
  session_start();
  if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && !empty($_SESSION['id'])) //Add more conditions here
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

in other files:

```
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/sessions.php");
if (!check_session()) {
    die("Forbidden"); //Or redirect to a login page
}
```

Comment: yes some other articles do say that HTTP_USER_AGENT wont be much of a help. So how best to secure the session to make sure that only valid users are accessing not some scanners etc ? For the _GET how normally do you ensure it is present you mean check is not empty? How to check the types if its a varchar? For string what is allowed or valid content in terms of storing to the db ? Which part should I put in a function you mean to say the whole of if and else ?

Comment: What do you want exactly? To only allow valid and logged in users, or to allow anything that does not look like a bot/scanner?

Comment: Mysql ``varchars` are strings in php. The notion of "valid content" depends of your application. You should check for non standard characters when someone submit a username or email address for instance.

Comment: @ I want to allow only valid and logged user and disable any other access it can other user or even bot or scanner

Comment: actually when the user enter I do check in javascript but for get value that wont be helpful. What is defined as non-standard characters. Normally I got a textbox with search fucntionality which I am worried for that one.

Comment: Are you saying that is part of code I keep in one more file and just include here? if(!( isset($_SESSION['eID']) && !empty($_SESSION['eID']) && isset($_SESSION['uID']) && !empty($_SESSION['uID']) && isset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && !empty($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ))
{

}
else
{

Comment: so where you suggest to put another folder is it? I knwo this scanner will go for it right? What is your suggest where to put create a new folder n store there? But how secure is that ?

Comment: How do you suggest to stop scanner or bot to access or browse the dirctory beside disabling the indexing ?

Comment: Preventing access to a folder or disabling directory indexing is a matter of server configuration.

Comment: So from php site how you disable the bot/scanner ? Where you suggest to put the session file then so its not accessible ?

Comment: Where do you suggest to put the directory of the session.php ? Can I put out of the /var/html/www ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41267/discussion-between-zewaren-and-user2711681)

Comment: my server is centos so how wat is best advice

Comment: so what is your best advice for linux environment to protect bots etc